# Excel - Lookup - Multiple result across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

Im doing a work calendar, that should be filled automatically depending of the day of the week or of the day of the month. Meaning:

I have weekly chores (each are equally every week) and monthly chores (each are equally for every specific work day of the month).

The idea is every time i change the month of the calendar, is filled with the chores needed to be done for each day.

This is the calendar that i'm doing (the red cells are filled by hand, the rest is automatically filled with the formula below):
[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0HAB.jpg)

Week Chores sheet
[Sheet ToDos week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTzYl.jpg)

Month Chores sheet
[Sheet ToDos Month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdY7y.jpg)

I already filled the weekly chores automatically with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('ToDos Week'!$C$3:$C$98;SMALL(IF((WEEKDAY($C$3;2)='ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98);ROW('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98)-MIN(ROW('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98))+1;"");ROWS($L$1:L3)));"")
```

Works like a charm

But my difficulty now is to add the monthly chores

I Tried to add

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX('ToDos Week'!$C$3:$C$98;SMALL(IF((WEEKDAY($F$3;2)='ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98);ROW('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98)-MIN(ROW('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98))+1;"");ROWS($L$1:L1)));INDEX('ToDos Month'!$C$3:$C$91;SMALL(IF((NETWORKDAYS(F$5-DAY(F$5)+1;F$5;holidays)='ToDos Month'!$B$3:$B$91);ROW('ToDos Month'!$B$3:$B$91)-MIN(ROW('ToDos Month'!$B$3:$B$91))+1;"");ROWS($L$1:L1))));"")
```

of course doesn't work because the part "ROWS($L$1:L1)" of the formula will stretch and will not give me the first occurrence of the month chores (in case there's week chores in the same day), but the third or fourth..

Can you help me with this?

Comment: I think this probably needs some example screenshots of the 3 worksheets involved to make more sense (the work-list sheet, the `ToDos Week` sheet, and the `ToDos Month` sheet).  Just a couple of rows of data, with the Row/Column headings, and some correctly formatted data (even if you replace names/tasks with rubbish)

Comment: Consider using code sample formatting instead of blockquotes for functions in your question, it will be easier for others to read.

Comment: @Chronocidal already edit. Hope its more easy this way to understand what i need

Comment: @AntiDrondert already edited, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**{Big Edit}**  Okay, I've just realised I overlooked a *really* simple solution - as demonstrated in an earlied edit, we can use `COUNTIF` to get the number of Daily Tasks for the weekday.  So, we can subtract this from the Monthly Task count to correct the number.

To Simplify:  Is the task Weekly or Monthly? (You may need to add/subtract from `ROWS` to get it to line up)

`=IF(COUNTIF('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98,WEEKDAY($C$3,2))>=ROWS($L$1:L3), "Weekly", "Monthly")`

Use your existing code for Weekly.  For Monthly, just subtract `COUNTIF('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98,WEEKDAY($C$3,2))` from the ROWS to remove all the Weekly tasks:

`IFERROR(INDEX('ToDos Month'!$B$3:$B$98;SMALL(IF((DAY($C$3;2)='ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98);ROW('ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98)-MIN(ROW('ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98))+1;"");ROWS($L$1:L3)))-COUNTIF('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98,WEEKDAY(C$3,2))>=ROWS($L$1:L3);"")`

Replace the `"Weekly"` and `"Monthly"` in the `IF` above, and you get:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('ToDos Month'!$B$3:$B$98,WEEKDAY(C$3,2))>=ROWS($L$1:L3),IFERROR(INDEX('ToDos Week'!$C$3:$C$98;SMALL(IF((WEEKDAY($C$3;2)='ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98);ROW('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98)-MIN(ROW('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98))+1;"");ROWS($L$1:L3)));""),IFERROR(INDEX('ToDos Month'!$B$3:$B$98;SMALL(IF((DAY($C$3;2)='ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98);ROW('ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98)-MIN(ROW('ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98))+1;"");ROWS($L$1:L3)))-COUNTIF('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98,WEEKDAY(C$3,2))>=ROWS($L$1:L3);""))
```

**Old answer below**

---

Okay, there are 2 possible solutions I can think of here...  The first, and simplest, only works if your Weekly Tasks and Monthly Tasks are formatted differently (e.g.  Monthly tasks may all start "[M]", such as "[M]File Invoices")  In that case, replace the `ROWS(L$1:L3)` with a `COUNTIF` to count the Monthly tasks (e.g. `COUNTIF(L$1:L3;"[M]*")`)

If you have no 'easy' way to check weekly/monthly, the next option would be to use a `SUM` in the Array Formula to compare each entry in `$L1:L3` against the `ToDos Month` list  (e.g. `SUM(COUNTIF('ToDos Month'!$B$3:$B$91;L$1:L3))`, taking advantage of the fact that a `COUNTIF` where both arguments are arrays will itself return an array)

These 2 options should give you the number of Monthly tasks in your day, for the `k` of your `SMALL` function

**{EDIT:Removing the 'blank' column}** *This needs redoing for each week/row.  It is based on my test sheet, where cell A14 was 05/02/2018, E14 was 09/02/2018 and the array formula was put into A15 and filled down-and-right to E23*

`=IF(COUNTIF('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98,WEEKDAY(A$14,2))>=ROWS(A$14:A14),IFERROR(INDEX('ToDos Week'!$C$3:$C$98,SMALL(IF((WEEKDAY(A$14,2)='ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98),ROW('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98)-MIN(ROW('ToDos Week'!$B$3:$B$98))+1,""),ROWS(A$14:A14))),""),IFERROR(INDEX('ToDos Month'!$B$3:$B$98,SMALL(IF((DAY(A$14)='ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98),ROW('ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98)-MIN(ROW('ToDos Month'!$A$3:$A$98))+1,""),COUNTIF(A$14:A14,"Month*")+1)),""))`

First thing it does it check how many Weekly tasks there are for the day.  If this is greater than the number of tasks already filled out, it looks for a Weekly task, otherwise it looks to a Monthly task - counting the existing Monthly tasks as starting with "Month"

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't resolve my problem. The L1:L3, are empty rows that i'm using just to have the `k`, and isn't in any way connected to the list of tasks. So the countif don't have anything to return... just returns `0` when i tried it. But maybe the countif is a way to find a solution... not seeing how though.

Comment: Rather than empty rows, why not look at the already-filled activities for today?  I have added a new formula, based on each week starting on rows 4/14/24/34/44 and Monday-Friday running from Column A to Column E

Comment: OMG made so much sense!!! Don't know i haven't thought about it before!! Thank you so much for the help :D